# Why can't I murder this drunk guy and why is he a target? (aka: Where do I find Duccio for the Bully Achievement?)

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

While exploring the Constantine district, north of the Romani HQ, but south of the blacksmith's shop I found a small courtyard with a well wherein a drunk man is... well, being drunk.  Every time I approach this courtyard, there he is, being drunk.  The problem is he's got a red target on top of his head, which usually means he's part of some mission.

I first noticed him during the Master Assassin mission, "The Trickster, Part 2" where I was tailing a rogue Romani.  I poisoned him then, thinking he was related to the quest.  However, I still had to kill the Romani in order to complete the quest.

I've poisoned him, stabbed him a dozen ways, arrowed him, bombed him, called assassins on him, grabbed him and thrown him, tripped him, etc, and I can't seem to figure out what he's for and why he's on my radar as a target.  Every time he dies, if I leave the area he resets.  Killing him is worth about 20% awareness as well.

It's been several saves/reloads since I first encountered him, and there he is, enjoying his wine and staggering about.  What's the point of this guy?

Is this just a glitch, or is there some mission I need him for?

Comment: Obligatory "wish we had the murder tag still" comment.

Comment: @DoozerBlake I think [tag:fisticuffs] would be more appropriate in this case.

Comment: he's stuck in Groundhog Day :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This guy is related to an acheivement.

http://www.trueachievements.com/a157188/bully-achievement.htm

Beat his face up. That's it. With your fists, I shall add.

Storyline wise, I think it's the ex husband of your sister, if I remember well.

I shall add his wiki page, for story's sake. http://assassinscreed.wikia.com/wiki/Duccio_de_Luca

Comment: I was going to ask where I find Duccio for this achievement, but apparently the answer to this question answers that question as well.  It's a two-fer!

Comment: +1 for learning this is actually Duccio. I've just been stabbing him repeatedly.

Answer (score 7):

This is [Duccio](http://assassinscreed.wikia.com/wiki/Duccio_de_Luca), he appeared in the previous 2 AC games. He was Ezio's sister's fiancee but cheated on her. You can beat him up (fists) for an achievement/trophy (on the x360 and PS3, respectively), and he won't come back again

Comment: so...does that mean we won't be able to kill him anymore? :(

Comment: Maybe you can beat up his ancestors in AC3 :)